# i have exceed number error in nextInt() of util.Random in Java 1.8.74 (Intellij Idea 2016.1.1)

Tags: java, random

I tried to get a random number between 3 and 6 (inclusive):

```
public class A {              

 Random ran = new Random();                            
 public func1(){            
  x = 3 + ran.nextInt(7); // need Random number x from 3 to 6   
  y = 3 + ran.nextInt(7)             
 }
}
```

but it often gives results `8` and `9`! How it can be ?

I used

```
 x=(int) (3 + Math.random()*6);
```

its give 8 sometimes too...
where is an Error???

Answer (score 0):

```
3 + ran.nextInt(7); // need Random number x from 3 to 6
```

`ran.nextInt()` will give you numbers between 0 (inclusive) and 7(exclusive). If you add 3, you'll end up with range 3 - 9.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of why you need write your own code and understand what you are writing.

```
   x = 3 + ran.nextInt(7);
```

If you read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) for `Random.nextInt(int)` it says:

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

So `nextInt(7)` is going to return a value between 0 (inclusive) and 7 (exclusive); i.e. 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6.

That means that

```
   x = 3 + ran.nextInt(7);
```

gives you 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9.  That is what you are seeing.

The solution?  How to generate a number in the range 3, 4, 5, 6?

Work it out for your self<sup>1</sup>.  The exercise will do you good!

---

Lessons:

1. Read the javadocs.
2. Don't just copy code fragments.  Copying code is not proper programming.

---

<sup>1 - SPOILER: `x = 3 + ran.nextInt(4);`</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot i got it.....